# The superlative of sincere

Tags: degree-of-comparison

Is the usage sincerest gratitude wrong?Can we use such in acknowledgements?

Comment: Many respectable dictionaries list *sincerest*, most of them *sincerer* as well. However few writers ever really use them  except in an idiomatic/ literary sense. OP's context is fine for *sincerest*, there was even such a "standard phrase" used in telegrams. Not in formal writing, use *most sincere* instead.

Answer (score 9):

Consider the common phrase *sincerest form of flattery*. Where I'm from I hear *sincerest* more often than *most sincere*, though it's close. I never hear *sincerer*. Google Ngrams trends the same as my personal experience, and it looks like there was a shift from *most sincere* to *sincerest* in the 1980s but the difference is negligible regardless:

[image: N-gram comparing 'most sincere' vs 'sincerest' & 'more sincere' vs 'sincerer']

Comment: Never thought about this, but now that you mention it, yes. _Sincere_ seems to have only one comparative (with _most_), but two superlatives in somewhat free variation. Interesting.

Comment: So you say it's not a wrong usage?

Comment: @Edwin, uhhh, yes. _More_, of course. Slight brain fart there.

Comment: -1 Never use nGrams in isolation to draw conclusions. Use them for research, use them to support an argument, ....

Comment: @Kris: Doesn't the sentence "Google Ngrams trends the same as my personal experience" imply, that here it was used to support an argument?

Comment: Neither is personal experience a canonical answer, argument, yes.

Comment: See also my comment at OP.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps more appropriate Ngrams (English being so unpredictable) are [these](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sincerest+gratitude%2Cmost+sincere+gratitude%2Csincerest+form+of%2Cmost+sincere+form+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csincerest%20gratitude%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmost%20sincere%20gratitude%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csincerest%20form%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmost%20sincere%20form%20of%3B%2Cc0).

These suggest that (and my opinion is in agreement, but more data would be more persuasive):

1) 'Sincerest' is preferred to 'most sincere', though both are in use.

2) The degree of preference is dependent on the following noun group. With '... form of', the periphrastic alternative is much less frequently used.

Comment: 'Sincerest form of' is idiomatic, probably from *sincerest form of flattery*. There seems to be no other reason to prefer the expression over 'most sincere form of' other than the **usual difference** between the *-est* and *most * forms of a superlative.

Comment: _All_ of English is idiomatic.

Comment: Ha! All language is; all expression indeed is. Life is, of course.

Comment: I wonder why there was so much sincere gratitude between 1825 and 1835...?

Comment: Well that is just after the Era of Good Feelings...

Answer (score 0):

"My most sincere gratitude"  would be the most common form used. Superlative for long words tend to be made using more or most instead of the suffixes  -er -est.

Comment: How is "sincere" a long word?

Comment: The Ngrams Matt has dug out would indicate that this answer is at least partly incorrect. It is unwise to trot out rules of thumb to justify unsubstantiated ideas about how English _should_ behave in particular cases. English is often unpredictable. 'Sincerest' is commonly used, though not 'sincerer'. Arguably, 'sincere' is a classifying (or perhaps absolute) adjective (one is either sincere or not) so the fact that it grades at all is perverse. And although I'd go with 'My most sincere gratitude', if I had to chose, I'd certainly switch to 'Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why not *sincerer*? And I find that I correct guessed what led you astray.

Comment: @Kris Pardon? I'd say that 'sincerest' is just a pragmatic adaptation of 'sincere' – it's like underlining it, it's not a true superlative. We have the model 'merest' = '**mere**'.

Comment: I was referring to my earlier comment under your answer.